# Python subclass function changes subclass's instance to parent class's instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have written 3 classes. One is the parent class "Single_Ket", one is the subclass "J_Eig", and the last one is "J_Op" which defines some action on the subclass "J_Eig".

```
from sympy import Rational, sqrt, I
import sympy as sp


class Single_Ket:

    def __init__(self, label: tuple, ket_coefficient = 1):

        self.label = label
        self.coeff = ket_coefficient
    

    # Elementary Computations
    def __mul__(self, Scalar_Const):
        return Single_Ket(self.label, self.coeff * Scalar_Const)
    
    def __rmul__(self, Scalar_Const):
        return Single_Ket(self.label, self.coeff * Scalar_Const)
    
    def __truediv__(self, Scalar_Const):
        if type(Scalar_Const) == int:

            return Single_Ket(self.label, Rational(self.coeff, Scalar_Const))
        else:
            return Single_Ket(self.label, self.coeff/Scalar_Const)
    
    def __neg__(self):
        return Single_Ket(self.label, -self.coeff)
    

class J_Eig(Single_Ket):

    def __init__(self, j, m, Coeff = 1):

        super().__init__((j, m), Coeff)
        self.j = j
        self.m = m
        self.State_Coeff = Coeff
    
    def __rmatmul__(self, X):
        if str(X) in dir(J_Op)[0: 3]:
            return eval('J_Op.{}(self)'.format(X))


class J_Op:

    @staticmethod
    def J_Plus(J_State):
        
        return sqrt(J_State.j*(J_State.j + 1) - J_State.m*(J_State.m + 1)) * J_Eig(J_State.j, J_State.m + 1, J_State.State_Coeff)
#############################################################

psi = J_Eig(1, 0, 1)
psi_2 = 'J_Plus' @ psi
print('J_Plus' @ psi)
# This gives me correct result

print('J_Plus' @ psi_2)
# This gives me error message:
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'str' and 'Single_Ket'
```

When I tried doing the action 'J_Plus' once, there is no problem with the output result. However, doing this makes "psi_2" an instance of the parent class "Single_Ket", which I actually need it to be an instance of the subclass "J_Eig" for me to act "J_Plus" on it again.

I know that I can simply just define "**mul**" and all that again in my base class "J_Eig", but those operation will be basically small modifications of the same methods in the parent class. Is there a way to avoid such repitition?

Comment: `return type(self)(...)`…? You would have to override those methods though in subclasses which take different `__init__` parameters…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the constructors are compatible (which is a big assumption), you can. `type` returns the type of the current object, and you can use typenames as constructors. Consider

```
def __mul__(self, Scalar_Const):
    return type(self)(self.label, self.coeff * Scalar_Const)
```

If you give it a `Single_Ket`, then `type(self)` will be `Single_Ket`. If you give it a `J_Eig`, then likewise it'll be `J_Eig`. As I mentioned, it'll be your job to ensure that all of the subclasses have compatible constructors.